# How to export pandas Dataframe in to Teradata table

Tags: python, pandas, teradata

I have requirement of exporting a pandas dataframe into teradata's temp table .
I usually try with **udaExec** for connecting terdata .
So temp table has to be created on the fly while loading the data , since Dataframe on today might be 100 col's tomorrow might be 200 col's due to insatiability of data arrival i'm afraid i can't create a DDL and then load.

Please suggest .

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas.to_sql function (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)
you'll need to pass a SqlAlchemy connection and the name of your SQL table,

something like this:

```
my_pandas_df.to_sql(
    name="my_table_in_teradata",
    con=my_connection_to_teradata,
    if_exist="replace",
)
```

Comment: Also: Consider using current _teradatasqlalchemy_ package over old _udaExec_

Comment: Thank you!.. what if I don't have the table in handy .. will the above create it on the fly ?

Comment: yes, Pandas can create it for you. Notice that if the table already exists in Teradata, you can choose between different options: replace it, append rows, or raise a ValueError, using the parameter "if_exists".